# Setting ids to items in an Arraylist in a RecyclerView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I would like to set a different ID for each of my elements in this ArrayList. It is a recyclerview.

```
public void createExampleList() {
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mExampleList.add(new exempleitem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 1", "Line 2"));
        mExampleList.add(new exempleitem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_beach_access_24, "Line 3", "Line 4"));
        mExampleList.add(new exempleitem(R.drawable.ic_baseline_airplanemode_active_24, "Line 5", "Line 6"));
    }
```

I want this so i can add a OnClickListener for each of the items, in order to open different activities.

Comment: why don't you use the index value of your list?

Comment: Can you tell me more about that?

Comment: Can you show me the code where you implemented the recycler item on click listener..

Comment: mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                changeItem(position, "Clicked");
            }
for the moment it is a test animation that changes the text of the item

Comment: Here you can use that position value to check which item was clicked. And then navigate to your required activity.

Comment: That's exactly what i want : but i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

```
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            if (position == 0) context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityOne.class));
            else if (position == 1) context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityTwo.class));
            else if (position == 2) context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityThree.class));
           else context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityFour.class));
        }
    });
```